# Mediawiki css customization: set max width

Tags: css, mediawiki

I have set up a mediawiki webpage.
I find it annoying that the text extends to 100% of the browser width.

I tried playing with MediaWiki:Common.css to set up a max width, but so far I get poor results: especially it does not degrade gracefully.
Anyone tried and succeeded?
I was not able yet to find working solutions with Internet searches.

Here is my best result: (put this in MediaWiki:Common.css)

```
div#content { max-width: 800px; }
```

It degrades OK, but the right-navigation bar is off to the right.

Version: MediaWiki 1.22.2

Comment: Can you show your webpage where is the problem is?

Comment: Narek-T: Sure !
http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~cheritat/wiki-draw/

Answer (score 3):

For Vector skin put next lines into `MediaWiki:Vector.css` or into your `User:Name/vector.css`.:

```
/* set max width and fix the background */
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    max-width: 1280px;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 5em;
    background-image: url(/skins/Vector/images/page-fade.png);
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(50%,#ffffff),color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
}

/* set blue right border */
.mw-body { border-right: 1px solid #A7D7F9; }

/** fix the position of:
            personal user menu
            search bar
            the pop-up indicator of language selector
            search suggestions 
**/
#p-personal { right: 3pt; }
#p-search { margin-right: 3pt; }
.imeselector { position: fixed; }
.suggestions { right: 3pt !important; }
```

If you want to apply this CSS for the restricted pages, write down next line into your `LocalSettings.php`, but first check **[this comment](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:Tb6pin8p77wwn067&topic_showPostId=tb6rt6va7hreik5e&fromnotif=1#flow-post-tb6rt6va7hreik5e)**:

```
$wgAllowSiteCSSOnRestrictedPages = true;
```

More details could be found at:

- [Max-width in Vector skin to control site layout width](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:Rqxj1jgjhnr5ezt5&topic_showPostId=tcbfkgggre9n7qli#flow-post-tcbfkgggre9n7qli)
- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Spas.Z.Spasov

Comment: Hi and thanks. Sorry for being so long to reply. I'm a bit shy on modifying Vector.css because the next time I will upgrade the version of Mediawiki, it will likely overwrite Vector.css. That would mean a more complicated maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #globalWrapper {
    max-width: 800px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: I believe that the Vector skin does not employ `globalWrapper`. This thread seems at least relevant: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/max-width_in_Vector_skin_to_control_site_layout_width/reply

Comment: Sry this for monobook.